# Non-open source Version Control for .Net

Tags: .net, security, version-control, commercial-application

For complicated legal & security reasons, my company can't use any form of open source software, but I can't stand Visual Source Safe.  What secure commercial version control systems would you recommend?

Comment: There's a wide range of commercial version control systems - do you have any more specific needs?

Comment: Our team is relatively small (6 people), so anything on the scale of Team server would be overkill and unreasonably expensive.  This is why the legal constraints are so irritating.

Comment: ...and it would probably have to be something used widely enough to have brand recognition.  Something about the legal difference between the terms "best" and "reasonable".

Comment: TFS client & server licences are *included* with VS-Pro with MSDN. If you don't have the budget for MSDN, then you need to rethink your "no open source": there are very limited options for cheap, but not free, version control.

Comment: I don't think you understand the definition of open source software because windows xp contains BSD code.   It is 100% unavoidable to run open source software.

Answer (score 13):

[Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server)

I've used TFS 2010 for a while and I'm satisfied.

If you want a good start with it, I can recommend the book [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484268) (978-0470484265).

Comment: unfortunately, it's too expensive for my small team

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [comparison table of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software). You're likely only interested in software that has a proprietary license, if you're not allowed to use OSS.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is recommendations based on quality.  The world of commercial VCS's is strange and new to me.  I lament not being able to use subversion like everyone else.

Comment: Fair enough. Figured it might be useful to have a list of basically all your options though.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is [Perforce](http://perforce.com/); it's fast to use, and easy to set up. If you can get by with two user accounts, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I used it, but I really liked StarTeam from Borland.  It is more than just version control, I believe it has integrated ticketing as well.